# Magento 2.3 app folder is not reading by Magento

Tags: magento2, app

I have installed Magento 2.3 EE in my local and after install we see that the app folder is not reading by Magento with php bin/magento s:up command. if any one face similar issue and resolved earlier.

Comment: Do you get any error when you run php bin/magento command ? Try to run just php bin/magento c:c and see if you get any error

Comment: No, I am not getting any error. All the commands are running smoothly and all the modules from vendors are enabled but not from app/code folder.

Comment: are those modules shown in config.php?

Comment: No, after deployment also its not showing in the config.php